# Resource can only be used once?

Tags: c#, wpf

While designing my application's UI I ran into a interesting issue... I have a button with an image loaded from resources. I copied and pasted the button and everything looks fine in the designer, but when I run the app only the second button has the image.

```
<Window.Resources>
<Image x:Key="icon_edit" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/edit.png"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<Button Content="{StaticResource icon_edit}" Style="{StaticResource NavButton}" x:Name="btnNavEdit" />
<Button Content="{StaticResource icon_edit}" Style="{StaticResource NavButton}" x:Name="btnNavShow" />
```

### [image]

But if I add in 'icon_edit2' pointing at the same image it works.

```
<Window.Resources>
<Image x:Key="icon_edit" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/edit.png"/>
<Image x:Key="icon_edit2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/edit.png"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<Button Content="{StaticResource icon_edit}" Style="{StaticResource NavButton}" x:Name="btnNavEdit" />
<Button Content="{StaticResource icon_edit2}" Style="{StaticResource NavButton}" x:Name="btnNavShow" />
```

[image]

Why can't I use the same resource key twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the image appears only once is that image is a framework element and a framework element can only have one parent.  So your code first parents the image to the first button and then removes it and parents it to the second button, where it appears.  To fix this, use a resource that is not a framework element.  For example, here is one way you can accomplish your objective:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/edit.png"  x:Key="icon_edit"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
    <Button>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource icon_edit}"/>
    </Button>
    <Button>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource icon_edit}"/>
    </Button>
```